# Garbage collector and static class, variable

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

One point is wondering in my mind since last few days.
I want to know how Garbage collector work with static classes, variables?

As we all know Garbage collector keep track of objects that has been created in application and removed them automatically when they are no longer in use.
For static class no object is created and it loaded in the memory with the application debug.

So Garbage collector handle static classes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Static classes don't need to be removed since they are not objects and they don't consume memory (other than the actual class code being loaded by the .NET infrastructure). On the other hand static fields in static classes are objects that consume memory. They won't be collected since they are accessible for the full lifetime of the application. If you want to free the memory you should set the field to null so that the object the field has been pointing to becomes eligible for GC

Comment: Alright, your point is that Garbage collector never releases static fields or variables that's mean they are always loaded in memory. Then its will right to say that static should be created only for global const or variables?

Comment: There is an exception: in .Net 4, you can have collectible assemblies. And if an assembly is garbage collected, static fields of types in this assembly stop being GC roots, so the objects they reference can be collected.

Comment: @svick that's quite interesting thank you. Also it may be worth noting that the fields in static classes are instanciated when the class is first accessed and not when the program is started.

Comment: Formal objection: Static classes are objects too. Probably on the Heap (impl detail). Just always rooted.

Comment: @Stilgar: Not necessarily. *When* the fields are initialised is determined by whether or not the class is marked as `beforefieldinit`. (And if the class *is* marked as `beforefieldinit` then the fields are initialised at a non-deterministic time, at least in theory.) See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx for more info.

Comment: Can anyone clear the point here, when static class variable instanciated? Is it when class is first accessed or when the program is started?  discussion creating some confusion for me :(

Comment: Obviously it depends on the attribute.

Comment: @Amit: It's subtle and complicated, and not usually something that you need to worry about. For more info take a look at the article I linked to: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

He is never gonna release them. ( e.g. in WEB its until restart of the IIS).

They'll never say  :" No one is referencing me so i'm free to go"

also

you can never do new to Static Class....
so its usages is merely by Class object ( not the instance).

So .net doesn't take any chances and keep it out of GC.