# Garbage collector is not taking care of my unnecessary resources

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
                               ClassParent
                        Has a shared Field(DataSet)
                                   |
                                   |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                  |                   |                       |
   #                  #                   #          ~~~~~~~~~~   #
 ClassChild1         ClassChild2         ClassChild3             ClassChild'N'
```

The above diagram states the picture of my current case. The ClassChild1 ... N are the forms that i am working on. That forms are actually utilizing that shared dataset during the runtime. But i just realised that when ever i am closing all the opened forms one by one, That shared field not getting disposed even after i closes all the forms.

I wonder that this is a natural behavior or something abnormal. If it is abnormal then, can anybody tell me the exact way to handle this properly.?

Comment: Duplicate of [Garbage collector and static class, variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079887/garbage-collector-and-static-class-variable). `Shared` = `static`.

Comment: To those voting to close as duplicate: 1) There is a specific question here: "Can anybody tell me the exact way to handle this properly?" whereas your suggested duplicate is a general question about the behaviour of the GC, whose answers don't address *this* question; 2) Your suggested duplicate, apart from talking in C#-specific terms, isn't a great candidate for being the authoritative question on the subject, at least not without editing.

Comment: _the exact way to handle this properly?_  - Yes, avoid shared data, especially resources.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If i avoid declaring that data shared, Then that particular variable will hold a place in each instance of those classes. That will not be a fair one.

Comment: You can share through the reference, no need for a Shared field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shared objects` won't be collected since they are accessible for the full lifetime of the application. This is one of the main concerns of using shared variables. They are always wasting/using memory.

It you set a shared variable to `null`, it will not be referenced anymore and It will be collected by GC

Comment: `won't be collected since they are accessible for the full lifetime of the application. If you want to free the memory you should set the field to null so that the object the field has been pointing to becomes eligible for GC` I actually read the particular passage that you've copied from. But I really cant understand the last point. That is `If you want to free the memory you should set the field to null` what does that mean?

Comment: if you set the field to null you will free memory because that field does not have value anymore. You have to set to null manually because, static , shared fields are not collected. Thats all

Comment: So the rule is saying that, If i want to free the memory of static variable, Then i have to set its value nothing/null explicitly when the last form is getting closed.? Right?

Comment: Yes, if you set the value to null, that static/shared variable is not referenced anymore and will be collected by GC

Comment: Hmm i feel that this is a bit complex to implement in my case. Is it a good practice to leave those variables not disposed.?

Comment: It depends on how many you use. If you have for example a class with shared strings it is not very expensive. But if you keep in shared variable datasets with huge data that you are not going to use all time you are wasting memory.

Comment: Thanks mate, You have cleared lot of my doubts. (Accepted + 1)

Comment: Note that static objects are stored in a `object[]` which is referenced by the app domain - ROOT(AppDomain)->(object[])->Static Object. So setting a static to NULL may not clear it from memory if the parent `object[]` array is not collected, or until the app domain is unloaded.

Comment: Yeah, you have to clear the parent object, that is the one declared as static

Comment: IMPORTANT: Because this is a pure VB question, you should know that the use of the word STATIC as mentioned by Carlos, is refering to C#'s implementation of the VB Shared contructor. VB and C# both have something called Static, but they mean completely different things. VB Static variables are destroyed when the class they were declared in go out of scope, according to this [MS document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx)

Comment: @Steve, Edited static to shared to avoid confusion.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas Yeah, I got lost when you were talking about STATIC and sometimes I was not sure which you were talking about. ha ha

Comment: Static= shared talking about declaration